# Laptop runs slower when monitor is off

Tags: windows-10, laptop, performance

I connect to my Windows 10 laptop via Remote Desktop.

I have noticed that some tasks take significantly longer if the monitor is off compared to when the monitor is on. I know the monitor itself does not change the computer's speed, but that is the discernable difference.

For example a run of some software tests takes almost twice as long when the monitor is off as when it is on.

I assume the laptop goes into some kind of powersave mode where it throttles down the max CPU or turns of cores or similar. But what can it be? And how can I disable it?

I have tried disabling Connected standby via registry key, but it made no difference. But it does log a Connected Standby changed message in the event log at the same time that the monitor turns off or on.

The power supply is connected at all times. The laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad P1 Gen 3.

It seems that when the problem is present the CPU doesn't run as fast as when the problem is not present.

This is the task manager when it runs slowly:
[image: Task manager when running slowly]

While the speed varies, it doesn't go over about 1.6-1.7 GHz.

This is the task manager when it goes fast
[image: Task manager when going fast]

As soon as I activate the screen by either opening the laptop or pressing a button, it seems to throttle up the CPU and readily goes up to 4.5 GHz.

I can repeat a specific test run of the software I'm working on and reproduce the issue every time: The run takes 70-80% longer when the laptop monitor is off.

Comment: What does Task Manager say ?  I can remote into my own Windows 10 machine with no loss of speed at the remote end. It does not matter if the remote monitor is ON or OFF.